# Debugging PHP with Xdebug crashes in __debuginfo()

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp, xdebug

I'm trying to get Xdebug working in PhpStorm with CakePHP.  The debugger stops at my breakpoints as expected, but when I step through the code, it eventually crashes.  (Note: The crash occurs only if I place a breakpoint and step through the code.)

I'm working on a development machine, running:

- Ubuntu 15.04
- PhpStorm 9.0.2
- CakePHP 3.0
- Xdebug 2.3.3
- PHP 5.6.4

Depending on where I set my breakpoint, the crash occurs in different places, but I've noticed that it always seems to trace back to code inside __debuginfo().  I read about some problems with Xdebug and __debuginfo(), but I understand they were fixed in Xdebug 2.3.3.

Here is one example:  I created a project using only the CakePHP bookmarker sample.  I placed a breakpoint in ~/bookmarker/webroot/index.php, and after the debugger hit my breakpoint, I stepped through the code in index.php.

This is the error message:

> Error: Cannot access protected property Cake\Event\EventManager::$_listeners
>   File/home/mriley/WebDev/bookmarker/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php
>   Line: 454

This is the method in EventManager:

```
449:    public function __debugInfo()
450:    {
451:        $properties = get_object_vars($this);
452:        $properties['_generalManager'] = '(object) EventManager';
453:        $properties['_listeners'] = [];
454:        foreach ($this->_listeners as $key => $listeners) {
455:            $properties['_listeners'][$key] = count($listeners) . ' listener(s)';
456:        }
457:        return $properties;
458:    }
```

Any ideas of what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue as well.

Comment: [This Github Issue](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos/issues/164) reports that it's an internal CakePHP issue, that's still around 3 years later.